# Highchartsで複数をグラフを表示し、同一HTMLで違うグラフをタブ切り替えで表示したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Highchartsで掲題の表示を試みています。

`graphA.addSeries()`メソッドを使いループロジックを組み表示しましたが、最初のグラフAは上手く出来たのですが、グラフBは`graphB.addSeries()`メソッドで以下のエラーになります。

```
NS_ERROR_FAILURE: 
...Ga(Z,"dy",M)}P=Z}Ga(Z,C);b.appendChild(Z);z++;if(m){y=y.replace(/-/g,"- ").split...
```

お分かりになる方、もしくはアイディアでも結構ですので、ご教示くださいませんでしょうか？

graphA、graphB.は、次ページのような記述をしています。

```
var  graphA = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'graph1_img'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },

    // (中略)

});
var  graphB = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'graph2_img'
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    },

    // (中略)

});

// 表示が正しく出来たgraphA のロジック
for( var j=1; j < csv_array[0].length; j++ )
{   // ADD series:
    if( j == 4 || j == 1 )
    {
        graphA .addSeries( { name: dtname[j], data: dataSeries[j],  lineWidth: 0.5 });
    }
    else
    {
        graphA .addSeries( { name: dtname[j], data: dataSeries[j],  lineWidth: 0.5, visible: false });
    }
}

// 表示がエラーのgraphBの記述
// この行を削除すると表示は出来ます。
graphB.addSeries( { name: dtname[17], data: dataSeries[17], lineWidth: 0.5 });
```

**ブラウザ**
Firefox 46.0.1 _2016/05/03
Chrome 51.0.2704.79 m

**ライブラリ**
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
Highcharts JS v2.1.9 (2011-11-11)

Comment: ブラウザとそのバージョン、jQueryとHighchartsのバージョンはいくつでしょうか。

Comment: Firefox 46.0.1 _2016/05/03 リリース
Chrome 51.0.2704.79 m
jquery-1.7.2.min.js
jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js
Highcharts JS v2.1.9 (2011-11-11)
です。宜しくお願いします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/37250　マルチポストしたなら、質問同士にリンクを貼っておく程度の配慮をしてください。

Comment: まともに回答する気は失せましたが、複数ブラウザで再現することとHighchartsのバージョンを上げると解消される情報もありましたので、試してみる価値はあると思います。

Comment: 大変失礼しました。以後、相互リンクを張るようにします。
なお、『display="none"』がｃｓｓに入っていたため表示できていなかったようです。タブ切り替えを止めて（画面がスクロールする形式で）実行した結果、正常に表示が出来ました。
コメントいただいた、Highchartsのバージョンを上げる方法も試してみます。ありがとうございました！

Comment: アドバイス頂いたバージョンアップにより、本件解決しました。大変助かりました。ありがとうございました！